# XML call from HTML tag within XSLT loop

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How can I use `<xsl:value-of select='fullName'/>` in side the value attribute of an HTML button tag?

```
  <xsl:for-each select="people/person">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type='button' class='mybutton' name='users'
         value="<xsl:value-of select='fullName'/>">My Buttons
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

With this code I am getting a parsing error and I don't know how to change the markup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) instead.

```
<button type="button" class="mybutton" name="users" value="{fullName}">
```